# Cognitive arguments as rationalizations of emotional processes that preceded them?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, reference-request

I heard the following argument on German talk radio:

> Modern cognitive science indicates that our conscious arguments
>   are only rationalizations of emotional processes that preceded them.

Where could I find a recent, mainstream representative of this view (e.g. textbook author)? (It reminds me somewhat of the Libet experiment from the 1970s.)